# What is the difference between the package types of Spark on the download page?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, apache-spark-sql

what's the difference beetween the download packages type of spark :
1)pre-built for hadoop 2-6-0 and later and 
2)Source code(can build several hadoop versions)
can i insatll a pre-built for hadoop 2-6-0 and later but i work without using (hadoop , hdfs , hbase)

ps :hadoop 2.6.0 is already installed on my machine .

Answer (score 3):

Last answer only addressed Q1, so writing this. 
Answer to your Q2 is Yes, you can work on spark without hadoop components installed, even if you use Spark prebuilt with specific hadoop version. Spark will throw bunch of errors while starting up master/workers, which you (and spark) can blissfully ignore as long as you see them up and running. 
In terms of applications, its never a problem.

Answer (score 2):

The difference is the version of the hadoop API they are built against. To interop with a Hadoop installation, Spark needs to be built against that API. e.g. the dreaded conflict of `org.apache.hadoop.mapred` vs `org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce`

If you're using Hadoop 2.6, get that binary version that matches your Hadoop installation.

You can also build spark from source. That's the Source Code download for. If you want to build from source, follow the instructions listed here: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/building-spark.html